# Importing AspectJ file into another (normal) Java project

Tags: java, aspectj, importerror

I wanted to build a (normal) Java application called test5 and an AspectJ application called test4 that monitors other Java application but when I tried to include the Java project into AspectJ project it shows error of build path:

1. The project was not built since it depends on test4, which has build path errors.
2. A cycle was detected in the build path of project 'test4'. The cycle consists of projects {test4, test5}.

   3. A cycle was detected in the build path of project 'test5'. The cycle consists of projects {test4, test5}.

As reference here is the code of normal project test5

Main class

```
package test5;

public class ert {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    yxc a = new yxc();
    a.dfg(2);

}}
```

yxc class

```
package test5;

public class yxc {

    public void dfg(int a){
        System.out.println(a);

    }
}
```

And here is the code of AspectJ file in the another project test4

```
package test4;

import test5.*;

public aspect dgf {

    pointcut dff() : call(void test5.yxc.dfg(int));

    before(): dff(){

        System.out.println("adada");
    }}
```

Any helps are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by circular dependency between your projects in eclipse, e.g. `test4` depends on `test5` depends on `test4`. Break the circle by removing the dependency of `test5` on `test4` and make sure your `test4` AspectJ project weaves it's dependenct `test5`, otherwise the aspect will not work.

Comment: thank you, I initially thought you need to include each project in each other project.